# Easier image uploading in Mezzanine?

Tags: wysiwyg, image-uploading, mezzanine

I installed Mezzanine engine, and it works nicely, the inline edit is great, but there's one issue: image uploading. To do this you have to open 3 windows:

- open media library
- choose upload image
- browse image on hard drive
- click upload
- close upload window
- click on the new image in media library

This is incredibly painful. Is there any app/plugin for Mezzanine to ease this process?

**P.S.** The easiest image uploading I've seen is on GitHub: just drop an image in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload all images in a zip package.